# How to display an Expansion Panel inside a Bootstrap Card using HTML, CSS, Bootratrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to replicate a card like the one in the below image. I am using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap for it. I have a problem in creating an expansion panel that is there in the below image. Can anyone help me to create an expansion panel like the below image in my code
[image]

I don't know how to make an expansion panel in a Bootstrap card using HTML, CSS I searched in the net but I could not find anything. Please help me.

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <button class="btn btn-warning">Submission</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="space">
                    <h6 style="color:red";>KKR - USA</h6><h6><b> - KLA</b></h6>- GJAHR<h6>
                    <p style="font-size:13px;"><b>100</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="tip">
                    <img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:25px"><p style="font-size:15px">Nivedha S</p>
                    <br/>
                    <img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:25px"><p style="font-size:15px">Jagadeesh Balan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square">
                    <br>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-2">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Text 2
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And My CSS Code is

```
.col-sm-3:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 12px;
}

.col-xs-3:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.col-sm-5:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.col-xs-2:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
h6{
display: inline;
}
.space{

line-height: 2.5;
}
#demo{
background-color: #ccc;

}
.tip p {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10px;
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.icon{
display: inline;

}
.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-title > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.panel-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)** in Bootstrap is what you looking for.
You implemented it wrong, as the div containing extra details is meant to be outside the main div.

As explained in the first lines of Boostrap collapse doc :

> **.collapse.show** shows content

So your content has to be *somewhere else* in your case if you don't wont the whole div to be hidden/shown when you click on the button.

I added the following in your main div :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Open details
  </a>
```

Then the following div outside :

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a working pen !](https://codepen.io/hotlinedelite/pen/zYBXjba)

Comment: It's Working Fine. Thanks For help.